Proof of Bianchi identity with the use of Riemann normal coordinate
In many GR books the Bianchi identity is proved by taking covariant derivative of the Riemann tensor in the Riemann normal coordinate $$R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}(p) = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \partial_\sigma g_{\rho\nu} - \partial_\mu \partial_\rho g_{\nu\sigma} - \partial_\nu \partial_\sigma g_{\rho\mu} + \partial_\nu \partial_\rho g_{\mu\sigma}).$$ [c.f. Carroll Spacetime and Geometry (3.138)]
But the expression $$R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}(p) = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \partial_\sigma g_{\rho\nu} - \partial_\mu \partial_\rho g_{\nu\sigma} - \partial_\nu \partial_\sigma g_{\rho\mu} + \partial_\nu \partial_\rho g_{\mu\sigma})$$ is only valid at the point $p$ where we choose to be locally inertial (i.e. $g_{\mu\nu}(p) = \eta_{\mu\nu}, \partial_\sigma g_{\mu\nu}(p) = 0$).
Why can we take derivative of an expression that is only valid at a point. Carroll in his book explained that "the terms we are neglecting are all proportional to $\partial_\sigma g_{\mu\nu}$", but why? It seems that we can Taylor expand $R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}$ around $p$, giving $R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}(q) = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \partial_\sigma g_{\rho\nu} - \partial_\mu \partial_\rho g_{\nu\sigma} - \partial_\nu \partial_\sigma g_{\rho\mu} + \partial_\nu \partial_\rho g_{\mu\sigma})\big|_p + (\text{terms involving deviation } q - p)$. In this sense, the constant term $\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \partial_\sigma g_{\rho\nu} - \partial_\mu \partial_\rho g_{\nu\sigma} - \partial_\nu \partial_\sigma g_{\rho\mu} + \partial_\nu \partial_\rho g_{\mu\sigma})\big|_p$ will not even appear in the partial derivative.

I’ll let you fill in all the indices, but the Riemann tensor is related to the Christoffel symbols by a formula like $R^{a}_{\,bcd}=\partial\Gamma-\partial\Gamma+\Gamma\Gamma-\Gamma\Gamma$, with suitably dressed up indices.
So, lowering the indices now gives a formula like $R_{abcd}=g\partial\Gamma-g\partial\Gamma+g\Gamma\Gamma-g\Gamma\Gamma$. Now, when we differentiate and use the product rule, we get
\begin{align}
\partial R&=(\partial g\cdot\partial\Gamma + g\partial^2\Gamma)\\
&-(\partial g\cdot\partial\Gamma + g\partial^2\Gamma)\\
&+(\partial g\cdot \Gamma\cdot\Gamma+g\cdot\partial\Gamma\cdot\Gamma + g\cdot\Gamma\cdot\partial\Gamma)\\
&-(\partial g\cdot \Gamma\cdot\Gamma+g\cdot\partial\Gamma\cdot\Gamma + g\cdot\Gamma\cdot\partial\Gamma).
\end{align}
Again, I’ll let you fill in the indices. But now if you choose normal coordinates about a point $p$, then $g_{ab}(p)=\eta_{ab}$ and $\frac{\partial g_{ab}}{\partial x^c}(p)=0$ for all $a,b,c$, and so $\Gamma(p)=0$ as well. So, we see that in these coordinates, the only thing which survives is
\begin{align}
(\partial R)(p)&=\eta\cdot(\partial^2\Gamma)(p)
-\eta\cdot(\partial^2\Gamma)(p)+0-0.
\end{align}
Also, since we’re in normal coordinates, we have that $(\nabla R)(p)$ with suitable indices equals $(\partial R)(p)$ with suitable indices, and so it equals only the stuff above.
So, the point is that the other terms in the Riemann tensor are quadratic in the $\Gamma$’s, so when differentiating, there will still be one more $\Gamma$ left to kill that term when evaluated in normal coordinates at that point.

Wonderful answer! As I understand it, what we should do is to first write the full Riemann tensor and take the partial derivative and then change to the Riemann normal coordinate. So what Carroll seems to do (i.e. first write the Riemann tensor in the Riemann normal coordinate and then take the derivative) is not appropriate.

he does say the remaining stuff is proportional to $\partial g$, so that’s technically right, but yea that is a bad way of presenting things.

The Bianchi identities are a tensor equation which are valid in any coordinate system. So when one has proven them in one particular coordinate system, it will be valid in any other coordinate system.
Using Riemann normal coordinates, we choose a coordinate system where the Bianchi identities can be proven most easily. Once proven, they are proven to be valid in any other (more general) coordinate system.
The Riemann normal coordinates have the advantage that the Christoffel symbols are zero in their coordinate system.
It is actually like checking the Bianchi identities in a coordinate system which we would consider to be in free fall.
Also in Newtonian mechanics similar choices of coordinate systems are made where the calculation is particular simple. For instance one often chooses the z-axis being the normal to the surface of the Earth. One carries out the calculation with this chosen coordinate system, but one can be sure that it will be also  valid with a different choice of the direction of the z-axis.

what you’re saying is true, but doesn’t answer OP’s question. OP is (rightfully) saying that the first equation holds only at the one point $p$. So, we cannot take covariant derivatives of both sides of the equation (this would require both sides to be equal on an open set) and further manipulate. Carroll really should have elaborated more on what’s going on.
